# How to return a value of some type(some class) in a method which is contained in another class?

Tags: c#

```
 public class QuickSearch : Widget
 {
    public TreeView UsingItemTemplate(Func<HelperResult> html)
    {
        return UsingItemTemplate(html.Invoke().ToHtmlString());
    }
 }
```

I want to return a value of the type TreeView which is another class in the system, but I am doing this in the class named QuickSearch. How I can do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It is difficult to give a good answer to this question without knowing where this `QuickSearch` class sits in the grand scheme of things.  What is it's relationship to `TreeView`?

Comment: Thanks. There is no some relationship with the TreeView. They are both classes which are inheriting from the class Widget. So, these classes are widgets which are used in cshtml in asp.net.mvc. What I want to do is to make a method in the class QuickSearch that will return me a TreeView, after that I will use the method in the cshtml file to return a TreeView organized data on a QuickSearch widget.

Comment: @AndrejIvanov Then your code is correct. That method does return the type you want. Can you show the problem then ?

Comment: you just need to use the namespace that `TreeView` is in, in the class that you want to use it in. something like this `using SomeNamespace.TreeView`

Comment: @Franck is giving me error CS0118: 'TreeView' is a namespace, but is used like a type.

Comment: @odaiwa I am using it the namespace, but no result. Error still appears.

Comment: @AndrejIvanov You need to learn what is a class and what is a [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace)

Comment: @AndrejIvanov can you edit the question and add all of the code?

Comment: @Franck there is class named TreeView among other in a namespace named TreeView.

Comment: Can you show the namespace of TreeView and the namespace of the current class and your using statements please?

Comment: @sr28 namespace DS.Web.Widgets.TreeView
namespace DS.Web.Widgets.Search

Comment: So your TreeView class is in a namespace called TreeView? If that's the case you need a using statement with DS.Web.Widgets.TreeView, but it's probably a bad idea to have a class and namespace with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

"'TreeView' is a namespace, but is used like a type" - Your problem is that you have a namespace with the same name as your class. Change the namespace so that it doesn't end in "TreeView" e.g.

```
namespace MyProject.TreeViews
{
    public class TreeView
    {
        //class code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've misunderstood the use of namespaces. If you have a namespace for each class then you're going to run into problems. In this case, if you have a Search class and a TreeView class that are both Widgets, you could conceivably have both of them under the DB.Web.Widgets namespace. To do that, just update the namespace in each class to remove the 'Search' and 'TreeView' part in the namespace. Then the Search class should be able to use the TreeView class quite happily.

***Update***

If you can't refactor the namespace then you can get around it by doing:

```
public TreeView.TreeView UsingItemTemplate(Func<HelperResult> html)
{
    return UsingItemTemplate(html.Invoke().ToHtmlString());
}
```

Comment: No, I understand the use of the namespaces, but the things is that this is a project older than 10 years and the infrastrucrure was defined years ago. So, there are a lot of widgets, every widget has a namespace like 'namespace DS.Web.Widgets.TreeView' and under the 'namespace DS.Web.Widgets.TreeView' there are ten Class.cs files that are using the namespace DS.Web.Widgets.TreeView and one of those ten classes is named TreeView.cs

Comment: So do you have a using statement in your QuickSearch for DS.Web.Widgets.TreeView?